# Quartz Scheduler using C# code to start a new job immediately after the previous job finishes

Tags: c#-4.0, quartz-scheduler

I want to use Quartz Scheduler using C# code to start a new job immediately after the previous job finishes. Please provide code example for this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Open Source Site link provided [click here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).